# Can't put IP-address in database

Tags: php, mysql, ip

I'm trying to put an ip-address in my database.
If I do an echo like this:

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

But if I'm trying to put it in a variable or in the database it gives nothing, so in my database it says: **NULL**
The commands I used for that:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET last_ip='".$ip."' WHERE id=".$row['id']) or die(mysql_error());
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Can someone help me with this please?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the data type of `last_ip`?

Comment: dump the value of $sql - you should be able to tell if $ip is empty or if the SQL statement looks properly formatted.  Then you can paste the sql statement into mysql directly and look for an error.

Comment: The value is empty and stays empty, really weird..

Comment: Show us the parsed query once.

Answer (score 4):

You will want to make your `last_ip` column an `int(10) unsigned` and then change your `UPDATE` to be:

```
$SQL = "UPDATE users 
        SET last_ip = INET_ATON('$ip')
        WHERE id='{$row['id']}'";
```

Then when selecting you would use:

```
$SQL = "SELECT INET_NTOA(last_ip) AS last_ip 
        FROM users";
```

This converts the IP address into an integer for efficient storage. For more information please see the MySQL manual pages for [`INET_ATON()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) and [`INET_NTOA()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa).

Otherwise if you want it to be stored as text rather than in the most efficient way you can set your `last_ip` column to be `char(16)` and continue to use the `UPDATE` query you posted in your question.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply. I tried your SQL statement and I changed the type in my database, but still nothing is put in the database.
Really strange.. Should it be a server-error?
EDIT: even when I change it to CHAR(16) it doesn't work..

Comment: And if you `var_dump($ip);` before the `mysql_query` what do you get?

Comment: Still nothing.
I also asked it to some people here and nobody knows.
It should be right like this. I don't get it..

Comment: OK so there is problem further up in your code. Sounds like perhaps the variable `$ip` is being overridden somewhere. `var_dump` `$ip` and `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to verify the data they are carrying.

Comment: I tried the var_dump and somehow there still is no value in the $ip variable..
And the weird thing is, I can do an echo and print the ip-address, but when I print the $ip variable it says it's empty..

Comment: `var_dump` both variables as I mentioned above and paste them both here otherwise no one will be able to help you. I suspect that you need to trace the source of the IP back until you find the disconnect.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant, but I did this:
    
    <?php if(!isset($ip)) 
    {
    echo "no ip-address";
    var_dump($ip);
    }
    else
    {
    echo "there is an ip-address";
    var_dump($ip);
    }
    }
    ?>

And all I get is: "no ip-address"NULL

Comment: `<?php var_dump($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); ?>` as I said a few comments ago. Then __immediately__ after your `$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` do `var_dump($ip);`. Keep var_dumping the variables until you find where it is ending up `NULL`.

Comment: If you don't mind I'll hare you my login-page. I'm still learning PHP and I do appreciate it that you want to help me. But I not always understand what you mean.
http://paste.bradleygill.com/index.php?paste_id=286792

Comment: Try the following code: http://paste.bradleygill.com/index.php?paste_id=286795 I have added the `var_dumps` in for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit in my code ;)
I replaced it with my code. And I tried to log in and see if there was an IP-address in the database, but there isn't one. I also get the message (from my own echo) that the $ip-variable is empty.

Comment: What about the var_dumps I added. What did they print to screen? `<?php var_dump($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); ?>` is the most important one to see that IP address is actually available to PHP.

Comment: I can't see something new is printed on the screen, so I suppose it doesn't work?
If I just do 'echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];' Then I get the ip, but not in the variable

Comment: Sorry, but I am not able to debug it any further without that information. I cannot see anything untoward with the code so I wouldn't know where to go from here.

Comment: No problem! Thanks for the help.
I just didn't use it, it was for a check if there was going to happen something bad on the website.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct and should work. Unless as commented by @wallyk, the data type of the ip field is unsupported one.

However, just to make sure wrap the WHERE condition in `'` (Single Quote) and try.

Comment: `WHERE id='".$row['id'])."'"`